# What determines whether an app is eligible to be stored on external storage?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I received an email today from a user asking me to make it possible for her to transfer my app itself **(not its data)** to external storage. Since I don't use external storage personally, I was unaware this is an issue.

I'm unable to find anywhere in Android documentation or what determines which apps are eligible to be transferred to external storage. I considered the [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) but that doesn't mention the app itself.

Does anyone know the criteria for storing the app itself on external storage?

Comment: In the manifest file add to the manifest tag something like android:installLocation="auto" | "preferExternal".  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location  Indeed the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark this accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manifest file add to the manifest tag something like

```
android:installLocation="auto" | "preferExternal".
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location

Indeed the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission has nothing to do with it.